# python shortest path point

Tags: python, shortest-path, geopandas

I have a points geodataframe, and I have two geodatafram with inicial point and end point.
I would like to know the index of the nearby points from shortest path

```
gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy([0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5], 
                                                          [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]))
gdf_start= gpd.GeoSeries(gpd.points_from_xy([2.5],[0.5]))
gdf_end= gpd.GeoSeries(gpd.points_from_xy([0.5],[3.5]))
ax=gdf_points.plot() 
gdf_start.plot(ax=ax)
gdf_end.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you define shortest path?

Comment: That's precisely what i want, define shortes path and then select the points

Comment: Well, the shortest path is a straight line between points. Not the one you have marked in red. So I am trying to figure out the constraints and how the shortest path search should work.